# How to fix a hidden nav that spill out under the main section?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My hidden nav, which should stay under the main section, spills out when scrolling further down the page.

I have set my main section to min-height: 100vh with a background color and a z-index so I don't understand why this is still spilling out.

```css
nav {
  position:  fixed;
  top:  0;
  right:  0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ff5000;
  color: #fbf9f9;
  font-family:  "Anx Regular";
  font-size:  28px;
  display:  flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:  center;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #fbf9f9;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
}

main.open {
  transform: translate(-300px, 0);
}
```

```js
const toggleTag = document.querySelector("a.toggle-nav")
const mainTag = document.querySelector("main")

toggleTag.addEventListener("click", function() {
  mainTag.classList.toggle("open")

  if (mainTag.classList.contains("open")) {
    toggleTag.innerHTML = `<img src="close.svg">`
    toggleTag.style.width = "30px"
  } else {
    toggleTag.innerHTML = `<img src="menu.svg">`
    toggleTag.style.width = "30px"
  }
```

https://anx.superhi.com/workshops.html

Comment: Post all relevant code in your question. Do not send contributors to research your code somewhere else, we will just ignore your question. Also learn to use CSS smart layouts here: https://noti.st/rachelandrew/QEhSSc. You can edit your question and insert your code now.

Comment: you can just add the background color to the event1 div. This is a "hack" of course. You should definitely read what Dudi Boy linked in his comment and make sure you know how to use the layouts correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the `<section class="crit1">` tag in `<main>` that has the css `height: 100vh`. This appears to be shortening that section. I don't know where else this is used, but just removing that rule fixes it. You could probably also do something more specific like `section.crit1, section.crit1 section { height: auto; }` if that rule is important elsewhere.

Comment: aah thank you! I didn't set the height of section.crit1 in my css which is why I was confused how it was getting this but I just saw it when I inspected the page. I just set it to auto now and it's fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

100vh means the full height of the window where it is displaying (say 800px, for example) so it's not what you need yo solve your problem. You set a position: fixed to the nav so it's always in the upper right corner of the screen even if you scroll down. If you need it to show just when you are at the top of the page, try switching to position absolute.

Comment: If they wanted to mess with the positioning on the header, it may be better to look at `position: sticky`. Although, they may want to verify their browser support requirements here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position (they may also want to look at [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for this, as well).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem doing a task for freecodecamp.
I put both nav and main positions to absolute in CSS.

It stopped the overflow. Dunno if it will create problems down the road though.